# Multi line text field with unlimited length in document libraries allowed

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, powershell, column

**What I am doing**: Migrating Documents to SharePoint Online using PowerShell Script. Once document is uploaded I am simultaneously setting property values.

**Case**: In a Document Library, I have a field of type MultiLine Text. The amount of data which I want to store is more than 256 characters (around 1500 chars), hence I  would want to set the option `Allow unlimited length in document libraries` to true.

But while making it to true, I get a warning message as shown in below screen shot

[image]

**Question 1**: If I try to understand the last line in warning (refer below). Does  **application** means the actual MS Word or its something else?

> Only remove this limit if users will be uploading documents through
>   the website, **and not saving directly from the application**

**Question 2**: Is it advisable to set this on? Or there can be problems in long run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that if an item is uploaded from the web and your 1500 characters are added to the field, if someone comes along in Word or other applications that can leverage the document information panel, you could lose data if the file is saved back to SharePoint.

I've used it like this several times, the main thing to think about is the "finality" of the document. If there are still going to be a lot of edits to the document, then you might see data truncation in the client applications as it can't support that many characters. If all people are doing is uploading files and editing the properties from the web, then you are fine.